# Dictionary. Quick Fill

Tags: c#, dictionary

Good day. I learn Dictionary now and decided to create mini-game "Find Word".
I cannot fill dictionary and don't know where is problem.
`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> Word = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 
            int[] k = new int[99];
            for (int i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
            {
                k[i] = i;
                i++;
            }
            
            string[] value = new string[99] {
                "аванс", "адрес", "атлас", "вальс", "голос", "запас", "афера", "обвал", "кокос", "анонс",
                "лотос", "обжог", "нюанс", "дюшес", "опрос", "оазис", "окрас", "парус", "пафос", "пегас",
                "акула", "барка", "белка", "жажда", "кобра", "крыса", "почка", "пасха", "пачка", "секта",
                "обзор", "отдых", "ответ", "орден", "вагон", "венец", "ветка", "врата", "волна", "выдра",
                "газон", "глава", "гонец", "горох", "грудь", "дверь", "девиз", "диета", "длина", "досуг",
                "кабан", "каток", "квота", "кефир", "конюх", "кокос", "лаваш", "ладья", "лемур", "ловец",
                "магия", "мазут", "майор", "метил", "мумия", "наряд", "нерпа", "носок", "нитка", "недуг",
                "пакет", "палач", "перец", "песок", "пешка", "пожар", "побег", "позор", "приют", "птица",
                "радио", "разум", "ребро", "рывок", "русло", "салат", "салон", "сенат", "талон", "титан",
                "туфля", "уксус", "улица", "херес", "химия", "чайка", "череп", "шишка", "шорох", 
            };
            
            for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
            {
                Word.Add(k[i], value[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Word[5]);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

`

i search in net and ask to my study-forum

Comment: Have you used your step-through debugger?

Comment: ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
First loop iterates twice at a time as part of the `for` and then again you `i++;` inside of the loop. Is this intentional?

Comment: Not related to the problem or answer. But can't help notice that one loop uses the length of the array and second is hard coded to 99. It would leave inconsistency if the length ever changed. e.g. you add more words. Just an observation to consider when building out code.
As somebody else mentioned it's odd to use so many arrays but we all start somewhere.

Comment: Honestly it seems like you probably just want a `string[]` or a `List<string>`. It seems like you're (incorrectly) trying to create a dictionary of index to string, which is basically the same functionality as a list or string (accessible by index).

Comment: You're right. I didn't think that i don't need an array. And i didn't know, when i used two [i], i lanch [i] second time

Answer (score 0):

There are issues in your code, I have fixed them, Please refer to the below code.

you are unnecessarily incrementing the value of `i` (this line `i++`). and even if you fix that issue. then also you don't need an array.

```
{
    Dictionary<int, string> Word = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    //int[] k = new int[99];
    //for (int i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
    //{
    //    k[i] = i;
    //    //i++;
    //}

    string[] value = new string[99] {
        "аванс", "адрес", "атлас", "вальс", "голос", "запас", "афера", "обвал", "кокос", "анонс",
        "лотос", "обжог", "нюанс", "дюшес", "опрос", "оазис", "окрас", "парус", "пафос", "пегас",
        "акула", "барка", "белка", "жажда", "кобра", "крыса", "почка", "пасха", "пачка", "секта",
        "обзор", "отдых", "ответ", "орден", "вагон", "венец", "ветка", "врата", "волна", "выдра",
        "газон", "глава", "гонец", "горох", "грудь", "дверь", "девиз", "диета", "длина", "досуг",
        "кабан", "каток", "квота", "кефир", "конюх", "кокос", "лаваш", "ладья", "лемур", "ловец",
        "магия", "мазут", "майор", "метил", "мумия", "наряд", "нерпа", "носок", "нитка", "недуг",
        "пакет", "палач", "перец", "песок", "пешка", "пожар", "побег", "позор", "приют", "птица",
        "радио", "разум", "ребро", "рывок", "русло", "салат", "салон", "сенат", "талон", "титан",
        "туфля", "уксус", "улица", "херес", "химия", "чайка", "череп", "шишка", "шорох",
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        Word.Add(i, value[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Word[5]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: If we're optimizing then why use fixed length arrays? Or why even use a dictionary for this when the array is natively indexed? e.g. `Console.WriteLine(value[5])` is same result

Comment: Your comment was very helpfull. I remember this.

Comment: @Joe_DM agree, but we don’t know the use case that why does he need dictionary here.